# Threads and twisted can not be stopped by ctrl + c

Tags: python, multithreading, twisted

I installed the signal in the main method,

But when I pressed ctrl+c during running the process wasn't stopped,

```
exceptions.SystemExit: 0
^CKilled by user
Unhandled Error
```

**EventTrigger** and **MemoryInfo** are classes inherit from threading

and **HttpStreamClient** is a class inferits from twosted.reactor

How to kill my process by ctrl+c , thanks

### Code

```
def signal_handler(*args):
    print("Killed by user")
    # teardown()
    sys.exit(0)

def install_signal():
    for sig in (SIGABRT, SIGILL, SIGINT, SIGSEGV, SIGTERM):
        signal(sig, signal_handler)



def main():
    try:
        global cgi, config
        install_signal()
        config = Config().read_file(sys.argv[1])[0]
        init_export_folder()
        setup_logging()

        threads = [
            EventTrigger(config),
            MemoryInfo(config),
        ]
        for thr in threads:
            thr.setDaemon(True)
            thr.start()

        HttpStreamClient(config).run()

        for thr in threads:
            thr.join()

    except BaseException as e:
        traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
        raise e
```

Comment: What is `EventTrigger`? What is `MemoryInfo`? This is nowhere near enough information to answer the question.

Comment: @Glyph 

EventTrigger and MemoryInfo are classes inherit from threading

and HttpStreamClient is a class inferits from twosted.reactor

Comment: Maybe the question should have the "twosted" tag instead of the "twisted" tag then?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be the forceful nature that you are terminating the process.

While using twisted you should call `reactor.stop()` to get the initial `run` call to stop blocking.

If you change your `signal_handler` to shutdown the reactor.

```
def signal_handler(*args):
    print("Killed by user")
    reactor.stop()
```

Your threads could still keep the process alive.  [`Thread.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) doesn't forcefully stop a thread, which in general is never really a good idea.  If `EventTrigger` or `MemoryInfo` are still running the `thr.join` will block.  You will need a mechanism to stop threads.  Maybe take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

sys.exit() raises a Python exception; I'm pretty sure raising an exception in a signal handler does not do much. Either call reactor.stop() as Alex says or use os._exit(0). Be aware that using os._exit(0) will terminate the process without further ado.